# Android: get real battery capacity left

Tags: android, power-management

I'm wondering, is there any way to find out how much of the aging battery's capacity left compared to its initial capacity? Something like "energy-full" vs "energy-full-design" provided by upower utility from Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no

But:

The [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) has a `EXTRA_HEALTH` property, which maybe give you the information you could use.

```
BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD 
BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD 
BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD 
BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT 
BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE 
BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Oh...okay. Never thought it may be a problem to have that info :(

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve battery changes by using the following code:

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

There is also a BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH flag to use. I have never used it personally so I can't tell what that is.